# Passing value from PowerShell script task (variable) into subsequent task within the same agent job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script-1) link to set a variable in a task such that it can be used in another task in the same agent job.

In a PowerShell script task I am using the foll. line to set variable:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
```

1. The next section on the link shows how to read variable - it has got arguments and script. Where do I have to enter the arguments? Is it into another powershell task? This next part suggests that I also need to set `isOutput=true` when the variable needs to be used by another task - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#using-variables-as-task-inputs
2. I am confused between accessing the variable set in above step. If I want to fetch the value in another PowerShell task or if I want to pass the value to another non-powershell task, then should I use `$(sauce)` or `$env:SAUCE` to fetch/send the value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read the variable with another PowerShell task, the simple way is:

- For inline script:

  `Write-Host $(sauce)`
- For file script:

  `Write-Host $env:sauce`

You don't need to add the `isOutput=true`.

My YAML:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Set var'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./test.ps1

- powershell: |
   Write-Host $(sauce)
 displayName: 'Read inline'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Read from file'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./read.ps1
```

The file `test.ps1` is:

[image]

The file `read.pd1` is:

[image]

The build output is:

[image]

Comment: But the link says: "This does not update the environment variables, but it does make the new variable available to downstream steps within the same job.". So how are you using $env:sauce ?

Comment: If the powershell that sets variable is in a file instead of inline script, then I have to set isOutput = true and give the task a name (say 'producer'). Then use the variable as producer.sauce in subsequent tasks. Otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes this is right, but you cannot use $(sauce) as part of azure task arguments unless you use isOutput=true. Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, I tried this, I can pass an argument even I do not use `isOutput`.

Comment: For me, $(sauce) does not work as part of a non powershell script (for example - if I try to use it as part of argument). It works if I use isOutput=true and then $(producer.sauce)

Comment: Interesting! but I guess you understand now how it works :)